# How compile and run java project with multiple class using command line?

Tags: java, windows, terminal, command, command-line-interface

When I try to compile with javac .Main

```
D:\Desktop\Development\Java\Section 4\Abstract
❯ javac -classpath . *.java
error: Invalid filename: *.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>    
use --help for a list of possible options
[17:37]  Shell                                                                                                                                                                                                         xUSAGE 174ms  
Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Student st1 = new Student("John");
        ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class Main
Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Student st1 = new Student("John");
                          ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class Main
2 errors
```

But I able to compile it succesfully with

```
D:\Desktop\Development\Java\Section 4\Abstract\src\com\Testing
>javac -classpath . *.java
```

Although I still haven't figured it out how to run the Main class

```
java Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Main                                  
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/Testing/Main (wrong name: Main)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use straight `javac` to compile (really, don't - use a build system), you have to specify the files where they are on the file system. so not `*.java`, but `src\com\Testing\*.java`. Yes, if you have many packages, this means an extremely large command line.

`java`'s argument takes a class name - a fully qualified one. Not a path.

If you have this source file:

```
package com.foo;

public class Bar {
  public static void main(String[] args) { .. }
}
```

Then:

- It should be in `projectRoot/src/main/java/com/foo/Bar.java` where `projectRoot` is whatever dir serves as your main project folder, `src/main/java` can be just `src`, or `src/whatever` - or something to indicate the kind of sub-project this covers, `com/foo` matches the package statement, and `Bar` matches the public class name.
- When compiling a `Bar.class` falls out of it; this should be in `projectRoot/bin/com/foo/Bar.class` or similar, where `bin` might also be `build`. But the `com/foo/Bar.class` part is mandatory - class files *have to be* in a subdir structure that matches package.
- To run this file, you would put `projectRoot/bin` on the classpath and then write out the full classname. So, if you're in the projectDir right now, `java -cp bin com.foo.Bar`.